# Should I use ㅂ니다 in the sentence "this is an apple"?

Tags: word-usage, verb

Is it correct to say "이거는 사괍니다?

Comment: By "_say_," if you mean "_pronounce_": yes, it often gets contracted. If you mean "_spell_": officially no, except for a direct transcription of what was actually spoken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

사과 is a noun

ㅂ니다 is used to end a formal sentence by adding it to a verb without 받침

ㅂ니다 is never added to a noun

The correct form of your question is 이것은 사과**입니다**.

Comment: Thank you but what do you mean when you say "by adding it to a very"? And in the correct form of my question that you've written, shouldn't 사과 and 입니다 be in the same word?

Comment: @ematavox see edit

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, though I think it's less common in writing.  The root "-이-" if the copula is frequently omitted after a vowel, though exactly how often depends on what follows after that.  E.g.,

> 저것은 책이다 / 저것은 학교다 (OK) / 저것은 학교이다 (OK?)

> 저게 책이냐? / 저게 학교냐? (OK) / 저게 학교이냐? (weird)

In both case, "학교이다" and especially "학교이냐" sound less natural to me.  So, in the same vein, "사과입니다" can become "사괍니다" - however, unlike the examples above, in this case I think "사과입니다" is considered "better", especially when writing.

Also there are cases where -이- **cannot** be omitted at all, even after a vowel:

> 일등인 사람 / 둘째인 사람 (OK) / 둘짼 사람 (X: can only mean "둘째는 사람이다")

See also: [국립국어원](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=59089), [나무위키](https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%84%9C%EC%88%A0%EA%B2%A9%20%EC%A1%B0%EC%82%AC%EC%99%80%20%27%EC%95%84%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4%27%EC%9D%98%20%ED%99%9C%EC%9A%A9)

Comment: I don't know if you've considered it, but remember that I'm talking only abiut the specific formal 입니다\ㅂ니가 form.

Comment: I believe the best way to understand a specific form is to compare it with other similar forms and see how they behave similarly or differently.

Comment: Ok, but instead I asked you 

Comment: I think they’re different cases. Unlike “-이다” and “-다,” the ending “-ᆸ니다” cannot be appended to a noun, according to its official (the NIKL’s) definition.